# Closing mongodb connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, connection

I use native mongodb driver with Expressjs, I don't want to open and close connections on a regular basis in my routes. I want to open once use one connection in all my next() functions and then close when done.

I saw that after opening a connection I can pass the db object to next() functions in request object and use it.

When I try to close the connection like var db=req.db; db.close(); it throws an error.

Inorder to solve this issue I have decided to use settimeout function to close my connection.

I can pass around and use the db obj and send response and the after 1-2 seconds db obj is closed by settimeout.

I'm worried if the requests are more will the settimeout functions effect the servers performance. If I use this trick to manage my db connections.

Comment: I found the answer I was closing db instead of client in new 3.6 mongodb version things have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I forgot to do:

```
db=client.db('test')
```

and:

```
db.close();
```

Change in later versions can't directly open db without getting the client, using native `mongodb-nodejs` driver.